# Replace styleName="some-class-name" with className={styles['action-drawer-content']

Tags: regex, reactjs

I have `styleName="some-class-name"` pattern in my whole project and I must replace it with `className={styles['action-drawer-content']` in my React JS application.

I am trying to find a Regex pattern that can wrap everything inside those double quotes.

Any help please :pray::skin-tone-2:

I have seen somewhere that I could use `$1` as variable, but not entirely sure when and where I have used that. Could be an other language as well.

I am using PHP Storm as IDE so could just run a regex across the whole project.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/2exeso/1) what you need?

Comment: Fantastic @R.Schifini! I had to tweak it a bit but it totally worked! https://regex101.com/r/7UncLo/2 Thank you so much mate.

Answer (score 1):

As per @R.Schifini answer I had to write my regex as follows:

```
styleName="([\w'-]+)"
```

and to replace it :

```
className={styles['$1']}
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/7UncLo/2